# Sub query calculation

Tags: sql, subquery

How can I get my subquery to calculate each employees On-Time rate, group them, and then sort them in Desc order?

```
SELECT 
    EMPLOYEE_NAME AS EMPLOYEE, 
    (
        SELECT 
        (
            SELECT 
                CAST(COUNT(APE_BUSDRIVER_STATUS_OBJID) AS DECIMAL) 
            FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN 
            WHERE APE_AREA_OBJID = 3 
                  AND YEAR_TIME = '2014' 
                  AND ACTIVE = 1 
                  AND APE_BUSDRIVER_STATUS_OBJID = 1
        )
        /
        ( 
            SELECT 
                CAST(COUNT(APE_BUSDRIVER_STATUS_OBJID) AS DECIMAL) 
            FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN 
            WHERE APE_AREA_OBJID = 3 
                  AND YEAR_TIME = '2014' 
                  AND     ACTIVE     = 1
        )
    ) AS YIELD
FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN 
WHERE YEAR_TIME = '2014' 
      AND APE_AREA_OBJID = 3 
      AND ACTIVE = 1 
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NAME 
ORDER BY YIELD DESC
```

RESULTS:
[image]

as you can see, the sub query is giving the same results for each employee.

here is the table FYI:
[image]

continued...

[image]

NOTE:
APE_BUSDRIVER_STATUS_OBJID:
1 = ON-TIME
2 = LATE

Comment: The subquery doesn't reference any ID from the EMPLOYEE table... that's the problem.

Comment: Why don't people use JOINs more?

Comment: @Nicarus how can i use a join for this??

Comment: Many times when sub queries are used like this, it is much better to use JOINs either to the table directly or the sub query so that you can better set the relationship between the tables/sets. In your case, it does actually appear you don't even need sub queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    EMPLOYEE_NAME AS EMPLOYEE,
    CAST(COUNT(CASE WHEN APE_BUSDRIVER_STATUS_OBJID = 1 THEN APE_BUSDRIVER_STATUS_OBJID END) AS DECIMAL) /
        CAST(COUNT(APE_BUSDRIVER_STATUS_OBJID) AS DECIMAL) AS YIELD
FROM
    dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN 
WHERE
    YEAR_TIME = '2014' AND
    APE_AREA_OBJID = 3 AND
    ACTIVE = 1 
GROUP BY
    EMPLOYEE_NAME 
ORDER BY
    YIELD DESC
```

Comment: I get this error:  
"Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near ')'."

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use a subquery at all; the subquery bypasses the where clause and gives you the same result for each employee.  I think this is close to giving you what you want:

```
SELECT 
  EMPLOYEE_NAME,
  CAST(COUNT(APE_BUSDRIVER_STATUS_OBJID) AS DECIMAL) 
  /
  CAST(COUNT(APE_BUSDRIVER_STATUS_OBJID) AS DECIMAL) 
  AS YIELD,
FROM 
  dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN 
  WHERE 
    YEAR_TIME = '2014' 
    AND APE_AREA_OBJID = 3 
    AND ACTIVE = 1 
  GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NAME 
  ORDER BY YIELD 
    DESC
```

Comment: You're always going to get 1 as the result with this.